# How do I configure the ADT plugin in the eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

On the developer website there are these instructions:

> Configure the ADT Plugin Once Eclipse restarts, you must specify the
>   location of your Android SDK directory:
>
> 1. In the "Welcome to Android Development" window that appears, select Use existing SDKs.
> 2. Browse and select the location of the Android SDK directory you recently downloaded and      unpacked.
> 3. Click Next.
>
> Your Eclipse IDE is now set up to develop Android apps, but you need
>   to add the latest SDK platform tools and an Android platform to your
>   environment. To get these packages for your SDK, continue to Adding
>   Platforms and Packages.

My problem is that I can't do what is written in number 1 because I don't have that option on the welcome to android... by that option I mean that I don't have the option to select "use existing SDKs"

Comment: Can you access the SDK manager in the Windows menu? If yes, you can select the SDK you want directly there.

Comment: `Eclipse` > `Windows` > `Preferences`. On the left column select `Android` and then on right select `SDK Location` > `Browse`. [Screenshot](http://devlup.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/android-installation-configuring-ADT-plugin.png)

Answer (score 10):

Install ADT Plugin -> Restart eclipse. After restarting the Eclipse if "Welcome to Android Development" window doesn't appear follow the steps below:

1. Go to Window -> Preferences
2. Select "Android" at the left
3. Browse the SDK Location
4. Click Apply/OK button at the bottom-right corner

[image: Configure the ADT in Eclipse for Android development]